# How to create a programmatic content based on user role (Drupal)

Tags: drupal

So I want to have a particular link come up on a welcome page for a user role (directed there by a rule), based on that user's other user roles. There may be multiple of these such links per user.

For example:

Say user Bob has user roles of manager, botany trainer and lion tamer. His user role of manager will direct him to the manager welcome page (already done), however, based on his user role, the manager welcome page will also have the links to both the botany training page and the lion taming page.

How would I go about doing this? Would I use the rules module for this, as well?

This is in Drupal 6

Comment: What type of page is the welcome page? (node/view/panels/etc)

Answer (score 0):

Few ideas for you to start with.. 
If you use Panels/Ctools modules, you can use access rules to display specific content only to specific roles. This does not require any php code so I think that's the best way, even if you know how to do it in php.

Current user's data is available as a global variable, $user.

```
<?php
global $user;
if(in_array('manager', $user->roles)) {
     print 'my stuff' // print the module you want to display. Usually module_invoke() or some function call.
} elseif(in_array('trainer', $user->roles)) {
     print ''// stuff for users with the trainer role.  
}
?>
```

Also, by core functionality, you can display blocks to specific users by their roles. Go to Configure link of the block and set visibility. Note that if you use php to print the block, no check will be run. So all-php or all-UI.

If the block is a View, you can set access at Views UI.

[user_access()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_access/6) function is my personal favorite to display blocks in such cases. it lets you place blocks almost independent from the roles. If the user has permission, display it. no need to assume that a particular role has this permission.

Also, unless you override by modules, blocks will not appear if the user has no access to the page. 
For an example, it's safe to show a node edit instructions block (it's ultra stupid to use a block for this case because you can enter submission instructions - just for the example) at node/*/edit pages without access restrictions. The user must be allowed to access that page in  order to blocks appear.